# awk syntax error help identifying

Tags: bash, awk

I can't seem to identify where the syntax error is ..I've tried to these 2 statements but nothing gets written to the 'BlockedIPs' file. Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
awk '/ (TCP|UDP) / { split($5, addr, /:/); cmd = "/Users/user1/Scripts/geoiplookup " addr[1] | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}'; cmd | getline rslt; close(cmd); print $1, $2, $3, rslt }' < "$IP_PARSED" >> "$BlockedIPs"


awk '/ (TCP|UDP) / { split($5, addr, /:/); cmd = "/Users/user1/Scripts/geoiplookup " addr[1] " | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}'" ; cmd | getline rslt; close(cmd); print $1, $2, $3, rslt }' < "$IP_PARSED" >> "$BlockedIPs"
```

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting give you a hint? Why not put all that in a proper awk script?

Comment: it doesn't give one because I call it via launchd. I had to modify the statement from this cmd = "echo " addr[1] " | /Users/user1/Scripts/geo | fgrep Country: | cut -c 16-30"   so instead of doing echo $IP | geoScript   I want to do geoScript $IP   I just can't seem to see where the issue is because it runs fine in the terminal prompt ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is primarily with quoting and stems from the fact that you're trying to call AWK from within an AWK one-liner. It's certainly possible, but getting the quoting right would be very tricky.

It would be much better if you retrieved the complete output of `geoiplookup` into a variable then did a `split()` to get just the data you need. Something like:

```
awk '/ (TCP|UDP) / { split($5, addr, /:/); cmd = "/Users/user1/Scripts/geoiplookup " addr[1]; cmd | getline rslt; split(rslt, r); close(cmd); print $1, $2, $3, r[4], r[5], r[6] }' < "$IP_PARSED" >> "$BlockedIPs"
```